# File name pattern matching in Windows command line

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have several files like:

```
a.txt
a$.txt
a$b.txt
b.txt
b$.txt
b$c.txt
```

I would like to print file whose name does not contain '$' using Windows command line for file name pattern matching like regular expression:

```
for %%f in ([^$]+.txt) do type %%f
```

or

```
for %%f in ([a-zA-Z]+.txt) do type %%f
```

But it does not work. How can I do this using Windows command line? Thanks!

Comment: in your example, every file without a `$` has a one-char name. If this reflects your actual data, `for %%f in (?.txt) do type %%f` should do.

Comment: ... or [turn off complicated thinking] even `type ?.txt`

Answer (score 4):

The [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html), like almost all `cmd` commands, does not support something like regular expressions. The only command that supports a tiny excerpt of those is [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), which can be used together with [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to get the desired result:

```cmd
@echo off
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%f in ('
    dir /B /A:-D "*.txt" ^| findstr "^[^$][^$]*\.txt$"
') do (
    >&2 echo/%%f
    type "%%f"
)
```

This could even be simplified by replacing the portion `findstr "^[^$][^$]*\.txt$"` with [`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)`/V "$"`.

Answer (score 1):

As 'Windows command line' includes `powershell.exe` as well as `cmd.exe`, I thought I'd offer a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) based idea too.

Directly in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Xiagao\Desktop\*.txt' -Exclude '*$*.txt'
```

In [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)/[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), but leveraging [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```
PowerShell -NoP "GC 'C:\Users\Xiagao\Desktop\*.txt' -Ex '*$*.txt'"
```

*You would obviously modify the path to your source files location, (use `.\*.txt` for the current directory).*