# File pattern matching in GitHub actions run

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to automate upload of my NuGet package using GitHub actions. I was hoping I could match the file name which includes the version number to avoid having to hardcode it in the action YML. It works if I hardcode the file name. I guess I just need to understand the syntax to use file pattern match. See last line of that code sample:

```
name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./Project

jobs:
  build:

runs-on: windows-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Setup .NET
  uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
  with:
    dotnet-version: 5.0.x
- name: Restore dependencies
  run: dotnet restore SharpLibHid.sln
- name: Build debug
  run: dotnet build SharpLibHid.sln --no-restore -c Debug
- name: Build release
  run: dotnet build SharpLibHid.sln --no-restore -c Release      
- name: Test
  run: dotnet test SharpLibHid.sln --no-build --verbosity normal
- name: Publish Nuget
  run: dotnet nuget push './Hid/bin/Release/SharpLibHid.*.nupkg' --skip-duplicate -k ${{ secrets.NUGET_TOKEN }} --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

How do you use file matching pattern in GitHub actions run?

Here is a successful build with hardcoded path:
https://github.com/Slion/SharpLibHid/actions/runs/998451423

Here is a failed build with my attempt at pattern matching:
https://github.com/Slion/SharpLibHid/actions/runs/998464157

Comment: I think you may use a `for` loop to get all filenames in the directory using pattern `*.nupkg` and run the `dotnet nuget push` inside it.
A similar answer to loop through files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066888/file-name-pattern-matching-in-windows-command-line

Comment: There is just one file. I just want to match the one file name that's in there.